# Java JRE 64-bit download for Windows?

Tags: installation, 64-bit, download, java

I'm working on a web site project with a Java component and am currently testing for cross-browser compatibility. Most is fine but the Java part won't load on 64-bit browsers. Looks like I need a 64-bit JRE to test. Where does one download the (off-line) 64-bit Java runtime installer for Windows?

The official download page is here: http://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp

Unless I'm blind, nothing 64-bit there for Windows except a link to notes. Said notes are here: http://www.java.com/en/download/faq/java_win64bit.xml#Java%20for%2064-bit

Particularly relevant excerpt:

> "Users should download 64-bit Java software, if they are running 64-bit
>   IE. For downloading 64-bit Java click [64-bit manual download](http://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp)"

The only off-line installer, as far as I can tell, has only installed the 32-bit runtime. Then we're back at square one! Am I missing something or going nuts?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

<s>Might [this](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/6u26-b03/jre-6u26-windows-x64.exe) be the download you are looking for</s>?

1. Go to the [Java SE Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) Page.
2. Scroll down a tad look for the main table with the header of "Java Platform, Standard Edition"
3. Click the JRE Download Button (JRE is the runtime component. JDK is the developer's kit).
4. Select the appropriate download (all platforms and 32/64 bit downloads are listed)

Answer (score 10):

I believe the link below will always give you the latest version of the 64-bit JRE
http://javadl.sun.com/webapps/download/AutoDL?BundleId=43883

Comment: The BundleID changes per version, This page lists the download links for the latest Java 7 version http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre7-downloads-1880261.html

Answer (score 6):

The trick is to visit the original page using the 64-bit version of Internet Explorer. The site will then offer you the appropriate download options.

Answer (score 4):

Java7 update 45 64 bit direct download link is:

http://javadl.sun.com/webapps/download/AutoDL?BundleId=81821

Answer (score 0):

You can also just search on sites like Tucows and CNET, they have it there too.