# Eclipse Kepler 64 bit not running on windows 7

Tags: eclipse, java

I use eclipse in linux with no problem. But trying to run it on windows 7 ,I ran into a general problem that MANY seem to have already faced. I tried all the solutions but none worked for me and I get this:

[image]

My current eclipse.ini looks like this:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20121114-150939.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20121107-162306
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vm
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

-Windows 7 and eclipse are both 64-bit.
-java installed from java.com automatically in C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7 (older versions already uninstalled),, versions match, and path in environment variables is set:

> C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows
>   Live;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files\ThinkPad\Bluetooth Software\;C:\Program Files\ThinkPad\Bluetooth
>   Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files\Broadcom\WHL\;C:\Program
>   Files\Broadcom\WHL\syswow64;C:\Program
>   Files\Broadcom\WHL\SysWow64\;C:\Program
>   Files\Broadcom\WHL\SysWow64\syswow64;C:\Program
>   Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common
>   Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common
>   Files\Lenovo;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Ulead
>   Systems\MPEG;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Lenovo;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\SWTOOLS\ReadyApps;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Intel\Services\IPT\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Symantec\VIP Access
>   Client\;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2011a\bin;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\

I changed the 512(s) in the ini file to 1024 hoping to increase the memory to slove the problem . didn't work either.

can you please help me with this.
Many thanks

Comment: I may be wrong but, isn't the path of your vm a path to a 32-bit one? What if you remove the line "-vm C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe" from your eclipse.ini? I am pretty sure that 64 bits vm are installed in "program files" by default, 32 bits one going to "program files (x86)"

Comment: @Kellindil yep, that is the culprit. just going to java website and opting to install java will install java in "program files (x86)" folder. so I followed the instructions in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038858/java-jre-64-bit-download-for-windows   to install the correct version of JRE (64 bit in my case) and edited eclipse.ini accordingly. eclipse is running now... thanks to you. would you like to compile an answer? I'll be happy to mark it as the correct answer :)

Comment: sure, just did so. I believe I compiled all the steps you've followed with this answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is in the comments of the question, but to make it more obvious for people that might stumble upon this same error :

The *eclipse.ini* quoted in this question defines the virtual machine with which Eclipse should be run :

> `-vm C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe`

By default, this path indicates a 32-bits Java (64-bits Java are installed in `c:\program files\Java\...` by default). However the question states that

> -Windows 7 and eclipse are both 64-bit.

A 32-bits Java cannot be used to launch a 64-bits Eclipse (neither can a 64-bits Java run a 32-bits Eclipse). Two things need to be done to fix this issue :

- Install a 64-bits vm (the how-to has been outlined on [Java JRE 64-bit download for Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038858/java-jre-64-bit-download-for-windows))
- Fix the *eclipse.ini* file so that it points to the proper location. By default, this will be `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe` for the Java 7 JRE.