# Charles web debugging proxy request java

Tags: java, charles-proxy

My operation system is windows 7 64bit.

I try to install [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) and when I go to run it always it stacks with this:

```
A suitable Java installation was not found. Please visit http://java.com/ to install Java.
```

I have installed Java in my computer and test it using cmd console.

Please, could you help me what can I do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2038876/2761073

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common issue on 64 bits platforms, because they support 32 bits and 64 bits applications, and in you case 32 or 64 bits Java.

Extract from [Charles FAQ](http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/faqs/) : *If you are using the 32 bit version of Charles you must have a 32 bit JRE installed, and vice versa if you're using the 64 bit version of Charles you must have a 64 bit JRE installed.*

Make sure you are installing the correct version of Charles (32 or 64 bits) **with respect to your Java installation**.

Answer (score 0):

You could alternative try Fiddler which does a great job on Windows.