# How to run load test for 3000 users with 50 loops in jmeter?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, jmeter, load-testing

I tried to run a load test in jmeter with 3000 users and 50 loops.But it shows this error.

```
[9.746s][warning][os,thread] Failed to start thread - pthread_create failed (EAGAIN) for attributes: stacksize: 1024k, guardsize: 4k, detached.
Uncaught Exception java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create native thread: possibly out of memory or process/resource limits reached in thread Thread[StandardJMeterEngine,5,main]. See log file for details.
```

I also tried to increase the Heap size using-
`HEAP:="-Xms2g -Xmx2g -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=2g"`

But the same issue of OutOfMemory persits.
Laptop's RAM - 8GB
Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think amending heap will help, the root cause of this error is that underlying operating system isn't capable of creating a new thread.

- If you're using 32-bit Java - upgrade to [64-bit server JRE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2038858/java-jre-64-bit-download-for-windows)
- If you're running Linux - check `max user processes` value using [ulimit](https://ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html) command
- Reduce stack size via [-Xss](https://www.baeldung.com/jvm-configure-stack-sizes) option

If you already tried everything - the only workaround would be installing JMeter on one more machine and go for [Distributed Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter)